# Case feed option is not displayed in case page layout

Tags: case, page-layout, casefeed

I am working on trail head modules for case feed. As part of the module, the last unit is to add the feed view to the case page layout.

When i am trying to edit the page layout of case, i find that the feed view is not available in the page layout section. I had checked all the settings and the necessary user permissions are there and i have logged in my developer instance as a system administrator.

My developer instance was created in 2012 and the case feed was introduced much later. Not sure if this is the reason for the issue. Any idea why the feed view is not enabled in my developer edition and what settings i am missing.

Comment: did you check this- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=case_interaction_convert_case_feed_user_layouts.htm&language=en_US

Comment: It is possible to set up case feed layouts in old dev orgs as I have one from 2012 with them setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new page layout, you need to select the option for "Feed Based Layout". You can't change an existing layout to be feed-based.

Once you've created the feed-based layout, you'll see a link at the top of the enhanced page layout editor that says "Feed View". You can edit the feed options there.